# ViewPager update previous and next Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have ViewPager and when I open fragment I update my bd. But the previous and next Fragment update too. 
I haven't more code for this just :

```
PagerAdapter pagerNewsAdapter = new PagerNewsAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    pager.setAdapter(pagerNewsAdapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(getIntent().getExtras().getInt(ITEM_POSITION));
```

How to prevent the update Fragment n-1 and n + 1 ?

Fragment code :

```html
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new, container,
                false);

       TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleNew);
       txtTitle.setTypeface(custom_font_bold);
       txtTitle.setText(ac.getTitre());

       TextView resume = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.res);
       resume.setTypeface(custom_font_bold);
       resume.setText(Html.fromHtml(ac.getResume()));
       resume.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_500_transparent));

       BD_ACTUALITE.updateViewAct(ac);

       return view;
   }
```

My ViewPager :

```html
ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Act act : arListNews) {
            FragmentNew frg = new FragmentNew(act);
            fragments.add(frg);
        }

        PagerAdapter pagerNewsAdapter = new PagerNewsAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        pager.setAdapter(pagerNewsAdapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(getIntent().getExtras().getInt(ITEM_POSITION));
```

Thx all for answers.

Comment: You should at least add the code of your Fragment where you update the db. Is it called in a lifecycle callback everytime ?

Comment: Sorry 2Dee, I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok,
    I implement the ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener and Override onPageSelected()